# i am trying to using one to many mapping in three entity using springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

consider an exmaple 1 2 and 3 there is one to many mapping between 1 and 2 and there is also exist the relationship of one to many mapping between 2 and 3.
first class entity(PatientLabReport):

```
@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="patientLabReport",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<LabTestNameByDoctor> labtestNameByDoctor;
```

second class entity(LabTestNameByDoctor):

```
@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="LabTestNameByDoctor",fetch =        FetchType.LAZY,orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<LabReportList> labReportList;

@JsonBackReference
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="patient_lab_report_id")
private  PatientLabReport patientLabReport;
```

third class entity(LabReportList):

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="lab_test_name_by_doctor_id")
@JsonBackReference
private  LabTestNameByDoctor LabTestNameByDoctor;
```

when i try to post it respond the status=200 OK but in return the error will be like:
bad string or Maximum call stack size exceeded of Expected or Expected ':' instead of '}'

when i try to get the status code is 200OK but it returns the error like:
Maximum call stack size exceeded of Expected or Expected ':' instead of '}'

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you try to load more data than can fit into the stack, which normally is 512Mb. This either means you are working with huge workloads or you have some recursiveness. It does not look like you have recursiveness meaning you should propably think about using a different way of loading [1](https://thorben-janssen.com/best-practices-many-one-one-many-associations-mappings/#Avoid_the_mapping_of_huge_to-many_associations).